# Installing multiple Linux distribution on USB flash drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb-drive

Is it possible to install multiple Linux distributions in a USB pen drive and use on it `ext4` file system and `grub2`?

I don't want to use any automatic tools like *Ubuntu USB creator* or *MultibootUSB*. I want to do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any software to manage it, I'm not sure. I would advise you to run live DVDs and install them one by one sharing the same swap partition (to save space). I would recomend you to unplug your HDD to avoid any accidental mess. I never did anything like that on a USB flashdrive tough.

Comment: I will use this method http://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso but instead of Grub4DOS I'll use Grub2 to it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Install grub2 to the pendrive and use loopback loop in the grub2 menuentries to run the iso's.

The bible for manually making a grub2 iso booter is here:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847